# Fullpage.js how can I link to another html page with <a> element in section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullpage.js

I want to use [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) scrolling effects for my index page.
It is easy to setup everything.

But as usual I have a problem to understand how can I link to another html page using fullpage.js?

For example, I want to create an **a** element who links to another html page`<a href="people.html"><img class="responsive-img" data-src="css/images/header_image.jpg"></a>` ?

Do I need to destroy all fullpagejs elements/functionality?
[like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41858850/pause-or-stop-fullpage-without-destroying) or it isn't even possible to do something like that?

Comment: could you share your code? It would make it much easier to comprehend the problem

Comment: Please share the code and show the code for the section in question. You shouldn't have to destroy or pause anything for a link to work. `fullpage.js` is just structured using `table` and vertically aligned `table cell`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using any kind of ajax technique to load the new page (people.html), then you don't need to do anything special.

If you want to have fullPage.js in `people.html`, then just initialize fullPage.js again in that page as you did in your main page.

An example of this can be seen in [the fullPage.js demo page](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/), where it has links to plenty of examples also using fullPage.js.